# RESTful webservice Moodle plugin Authentication fails

Tags: php, rest, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am using moodle rest plugins for mobile web-services and from [this tutorial](https://moodle.org/plugins/webservice_restful) I have enabled rest API and other related services as per the documentation when I try to test the web service then I got following error

```
{"exception":"moodle_exception","errorcode":"noauthheader","message":"No Authorization header found in request sent to Moodle"}
```

I have the cross check the moodle token even try may new tokens but no luck

here is me test php code to check the web-services:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "mydomain.com/webservice/restful/server.php/core_course_get_courses",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"options": {"ids":[2]}}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: {4838e6771cdbfd1eefbf37b3839587d9}",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

please let me know, what i am doing wronge

thanks

Comment: If you are using apache, on the host config you might need to add `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` to pass the headers (to the vhost or .htaccess). If you're using nginx you would add something  like `fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;` to your php handler